# Why isn't my method of saving a vector to a file and then reading it back out again working?

Tags: c++, vector

I have a vector that I am trying to save between runs of my program, and I need to save it as a char* to memory. I decided to convert the bytes in my vector to be read as a char*, then read it again later on and read the bytes as a vector (of unchanged type), therefore saving it between runs. The problem is that this method does not seem to be working. I am managing to save the 24 bytes that contain the data about the vector, but the values that the vector contains are changed. I tried this method with an int, and it seems to work in that case.

I read some other posts on the subject, where the values in the vector were pointers. I understand why that wouldn't work, but in my case the values are std::pairs, so that shouldn't be the problem.

Edit: my code. I know for sure that the read()  and write() functions work correctly. writeOrigin() and setUpOrigin() do things unrelated to the problem. When I run the code without adding anything to the vector, it works, but when I add any values to it, it crashes when I try to copy the value from _inodes to inodes. inode is a class that I made earlier, but the problem also occurs to the int in the pair.

```
void MyFs::writeInodes(){
    static int count = 0;
    int size = sizeof(inodes) + sizeof(std::pair<int, inode>) * inodes.capacity();

    blkdevsim->write(SIZEOF_HEADER, sizeof(size), (char*)(&size));

    blkdevsim->write(SIZEOF_HEADER + sizeof(size), size, (char*)(&inodes));
    writeOrigin();
    count++;
}

void MyFs::getInodes(){
    static int count = 0;
    if(0 == count){
        count++;
        int size = 0;
        std::vector<std::pair<int, inode> >* _inodes;
        blkdevsim->read(SIZEOF_HEADER, sizeof(size), (char*)(&size));
        _inodes = (std::vector<std::pair<int, inode> >*)malloc(size);
        blkdevsim->read(SIZEOF_HEADER + sizeof(size), size, (char*)_inodes);

        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < _inodes->size(); i++){
            std::cout << _inodes->at(i).first << std::endl;
            inodes.push_back((*_inodes)[i]);
        }
        free(_inodes);
        setUpOrigin();
    }
}

void BlockDeviceSimulator::read(int addr, int size, char *ans) {
    memcpy(ans, filemap + addr, size);
}

void BlockDeviceSimulator::write(int addr, int size, const char *data) {
    memcpy(filemap + addr, data, size);
}
```

Comment: It would be nice to see your code posted here in lieu of using my trusted crystal ball that I seem to have misplaced.

Comment: Can you post some code that shows your problem?

Comment: please post an [mcve]

Comment: I added the code. When I was asking the question I was asking more from a theoretical POV. I'm not asking you to debug my code, just to tell me if what I'm trying to do shouldn't work in general.

Comment: You can't read, write, and create vectors like that. Read about serialization.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the quick answer. If I did create and read them correctly, should this be possible?

Comment: @Gderu You're asking if it's possible to read and write a vector? Of course it is, just remember that you do the work, read and write the vector in a loop one item at a time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the implementation of `std::vector` can differ between implementations, they all are a variant of the following (highly simplified):

```
template <typename T>
struct vector {
    T* storage;
    int size;
};
```

In other words, the bit pattern that makes up a `std::vector` in memory does not contain the actual contents only a pointer to it. You will need to implement an serialization format (sometimes called marshalling) for vectors yourself.

You could, for example, use [protocol buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/) or [cap'n proto](https://capnproto.org/).